# Different number of batches in Stats and Frame Debugger counts (222 in stats, 55 in debugger)

Tags: unity-game-engine, optimization, unity-webgl

I have a unity project that I'm trying to optimize. I look at the stats and see I have "222" batches in a frame (with -111 saved by batching??).

When I check the frame debugger to see what they are, I only see 55 calls.

Any idea what may be the source of the difference? And what is that negative batching? am I actually making it draw more than it would without batching? (which is not true because I checked).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ6oD.jpg)

Comment: Are you using SRP/HDRP? In SRP at least I have the same issue, and I found out that we can ignore the drawcall stats in the "Main" dropdown and only take the frame debugger as a source of truth

Comment: Yes I'm using the URP. What a mess! :D

Comment: Yea, so I read somewhere (can't remember where now) that you should ignore the "main" stats and just go straight to the frame debugger

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would go insane trying to figure out.